# Order by followed by dependent order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with part of data like below . I have done order by on edition_id .
Now there is further requirement of ordering laungauge_id which depends on value of edition_id.

- Edition_id refers to city from which a newspaper is published.
- Language_id refers to different languages in which newspaper is
  published.

So suppose `edition_id = 5` it means New Delhi.
For New Delhi `language_id` are 13(English ), 5 (Hindi) ,1(Telugu ),4(Urdu).

What i want is to display for New Delhi , is display all English articles first , followed by hindi , followed by Telugu followed by Urdu.

> If edition_id=1 then order of language_id should be **13,1,2.**

Similarly ,

> If edition_id=5 then order of language_id should be **13,5,1,4**

Right now what I have is

```
Edition_id | Language_id
1             1
1             2
1             13
1             1
1             13 
1             2
5             4
5             1
5             1
5             4
5             13
5             5
5             13
```

What is required

```
Edition_id | Language_id
1             13
1             13
1             1
1             1
1             2 
1             2
5             13
5             13
5             5
5             1
5             1
5             4
5             4
```

How to do this ? Please help.

Is something like this possibe

```
Select * from <table>
order by edition_id ,
            case when edition=6 then <order specified for language_id ie 13,5,1,4>
```

Comment: sir i have mentioned above the rules..

Comment: Yes, but why `13,1,2` and `13,5,1,4`? Hard coded?

Comment: yes sir , the order has been specified like that..13,5,1,4..hard coded

Comment: @var ok i will explain more..please see edited question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a supplementary ranking table. I would then JOIN to provide your sort order.  Eg:

```
EDITION_SORT_ORDER

EDITION_ID  LANGUAGE_ID  RANK
----------  -----------  ----
1           13           1
1           1            2
1           2            3
5           13           1
5           5            2
5           1            3
5           4            4
```

Using this table in a query might look like this:

```
SELECT E.EDITION_ID, E.LANGUAGE_ID
FROM <TABLE> E LEFT OUTER JOIN EDITION_SORT_ORDER S ON
  E.EDITION_ID = S.EDITION_ID AND
  E.LANGUAGE_ID = S.LANGUAGE_ID
ORDER BY S.RANK
```

This way you can add other rules in future, and it isn't a huge mess of CASE logic.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid a JOIN, you could create a stored function which did a similar lookup and returned a rank (based on passed parameters of EDITION_ID and LANGUAGE_ID).

If you must use CASE, then I'd confine it to a function so you can re-use the logic elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no mathematical logic behind it, I would insert another column that can be used for proper sorting.
If you cannot do this, you can simply type out the rules for the relation like this:

```
Order By Edition_Id,
case Edition_id
    when 1 then
        case Language_id
            when 13 then 1
            when 1 then 2
            when 2 then 3
        end
    when 5 then
        case Language_id
            when 13 then 1
            when 5 then 2
            when 1 then 3
            when 4 then 4
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

without a fixed order colum you could things like that, but the logic is not comprehensible.
Assuming first criteria is length of Language_id,
Second is Edition_id= Language_id,
rest is order of Language_id it could or work this way:

```
Declare @t table(Edition_id  int, Language_id int)
insert into @t values
(1,             1),
(1,             2),
(1,             13),
(1,             1),
(1,             13), 
(1,             2),
(5,             4),
(5,             1),
(5,             1),
(5,             4),
(5,             13),
(5,             5),
(5,             13);

Select * from @t
order by Edition_id,Case when len (Cast(Language_ID as Varchar(10)))=1 then '1' else '0' end
                   +case when Edition_id=Language_id  then '0' else '1' end
                   ,Language_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You've probably considered this but if your desired ordering is always based of the actual alphabetical name of the language then there would usually be a table with the language description that you could join with and then sort by. I base this on your quote below.

> ...English articles first , followed by hindi , followed by Telugu
>   followed by Urdu.

```
SELECT E.EDITION_ID, E.LANGUAGE_ID, LN.LANGUAGE_NAME
FROM <TABLE> E LEFT OUTER JOIN <LANGUAGE_NAMES> LN ON
E.LANGUAGE_ID = LN.LANGUAGE_ID
ORDER BY 1, 3
```